# How to print multiple Excel sheets into a single PDF file?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, printing, print-to-pdf, osx-tiger

I am trying to print multiple sheets from the same Excel workbook into ONE PDF file. But it frequently prints them separately or only the first sheet.

I selected all the sheets and made them have the same page setup. I am working on Tiger and from the Print dialogue, I click on the left-hand bottom button, "Save PDF" and from there I choose "Save PDF-X".

Anyone have another solution for me?

Comment: For those using Excel on Windows: on a Mac, the print dialog always has an option to save as PDF as well. As such, I guess it doesn't really matter that the question asker needs PDF; the question could probably also read **"How to print multiple Excel sheets in one go?"**, regardless whether it is really printed on paper, or "printed" to another format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried multiple times to give the two separate sheets the same page margins and page properties, but it didn't help me one bit.

I fixed this with an Automator task that took me quite a while to work out, but once it worked, it helped me a lot.

Thanks for all the answers, though I really did specify in my question that I did do all the suggested solutions before posting.

Comment: Actually, this seems about as good as Automator. Does it just bring up all the PDFs, or actually combine them? I'm curious how it worked out.

Comment: What happened was the quotes always contained 2 pages, the first one being always the same. So I just printed the second one as PDF to the Desktop. Selected both on the Desktop and right clicked -> Folder Actions -> Combiine PDFs (my custom task).

It takes the files and sorts them alphabetically (declining in my case) and then combines the PDF's and saves it to a new file on the Desktop.

Comment: Good you found a solution. Please share the main details about that Automator task then?

Comment: The whole of the Automator task is described in the comment just above your's.

Answer (score 2):

Select Multiple sheets using Ctrl and then print using pdf writer to get one single file
vijay

Answer (score 1):

Just print the excel sheets into separate PDF files and join them using Adobe Acrobat Professional, if you have it. If not, don't sweat it: there's the brilliant open source [PDF toolkit](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/). Here's [a short tutorial](http://paul.luminos.nl/update/482) explaining how combine multiple PDFs.

It's very simple:

```
pdftk sheet1.pdf sheet2.pdf cat output sheets_all.pdf
```

Note that you can use wildcards and that the order of input determines the page ordering.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, but I am actually looking for a more permanent solution/fix. I print quotes to PDF everyday and need this to work better.

Comment: All I can really think of is making a fairly generic batch file using wildcards. The other extreme is writing a PHP/PEAR based exporter: there are well-established packages for reading XLS files and writing PDF files, but that would be seriously overkill.

Comment: Indeed, it's not the solution. But for the archives: for joining PDF documents one can easily use Preview as well. Just open one PDF document, make Preview show its sidebar, and then drag another **on top of** the existing thumbnail in the sidebar. (Ensure not to drag it *below* or *above* the existing thumbnail in the sidebar; you really must drag it on top of the existing thumbnail.) After dropping it, the thumbnail will become a comb bound booklet, which can be expanded or collapsed into a single thumbnail in the sidebar as well. Expand it and drag the thumbnails to reorder if needed.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks, I tried that, but it is specific to Preview on Leopard or later and I was using Preview on Tiger.

Comment: There might be an Apple Script solution out there that combines printing from Excel and PDF toolkit into a single click of a button, but I'm not familiar enough with Apple Script. Perhaps shoot a question on Stack Overflow and somebody can give you something that you can simply plug.

Answer (score 1):

Select the sheets you want in your pdf file (make sure you print preview / set print areas in each sheet that you want to print) and "save as" pdf. Makes a pdf file with all selected worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul suggested, you could join them together after printing, f.e. also using [pdfsam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/). As an alternative you can use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) which does support to create a query of documents and join them together.

Comment: PDFCreator is Windows-only (and probably would not add much functionality to a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kind of "options" button in the Save As dialogue?
On Excel 2007 / Windows the Save As pdf dialogue has an options button which then allows you to save only the selection, the active sheet, the selected sheets, the whole workbook etc.
I have no idea if this is available on your version of Office for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

When saving the doc, selection option and all workbook instead of active sheet

- Select and Drag all the PDFs into preview.
- Select all in sidebar.
- Print and Save As PDF.

Comment: I did that as well, but it still just gives me separate  PDF's instead of one PDF with multiple pages in it.